# Huge need of memory in FPGA

Tags: matrix, fpga

In order to implement an algorithm in a FPGA, I need to store a constant matriz of very large size. I have calculated I would need a ROM memory of size around 30 Mbits, so the memory of the FPGA is not enough. I was thinking to use any external device connected to the FPGA. Is it possible to manipulate such a large amount of data at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to manipulate this much data, you probably have better luck with DSP.

Comment: The problem is that although the matrix is huge, only a few of the elements will be needed at the same time so the number of operations with those elements is not too high... I only need some way to be able to store those data.

Comment: Is the matrix sparse by accident? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: Only if it has been read into FPGA registers. Going off-device, you will have an IO issue, being that, it probably will not be wide enough to get all the data into the FPGA - this will impact your latency (time) the most. But perhaps you need to do many of these and you can overlap the processing with reading - unfortunately making your algorithm more complicated.
Can you process this large matrix in smaller matrix chunks? Maybe that's a way to go.

Comment: Do you have a FPGA vendor or hardware platform in mind?

Comment: If you are using the zynq 7020 or greater there is a good chance you have enough BRAM for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path.  Store the 30Mbit in an external nonvolatile memory (flash).  Often you can use the extra capacity in the same flash chip that is used to configure the FPGA (assuming there is sufficient extra space).  Read the few elements needed at a time into a the FPGA internal memory.  If the bandwidth of the flash read interface is insufficient to keep up with your calculations then do a one time transfer from external flash to an external RAM and continuously read it out to the FPGA internal buffer.

Answer (score 0):

30Mbit is not so big to external memory.

You need a nonvolatile memory (flash) first.But you do not need to always read these from flash.It depends on your bandwidth.

If your bandwidth is too big to a flash, you can use a faster memory like ASRAM or SSRAM or HyperRam or DDR SDRAM.After you powerup the board,your FPGA can read thess data out from flash and write these data to external RAM.Then you can read these data from RAM.

In these cases,you have to consider the bandwidth and package and power consuption and cost and r/w function mode. For example, DDR SDRAM can achieve a high bandwidth when you read data sequentially.If you access the random address or skiped address you will achieve a much lower bandwidth.

After all I suggest you to simulate your function comprehensive first before you did the hardware work.